# Aumentando o limite do "file multiple"

Tags: php, upload

Estou tentando fazer um upload múltiplo de imagens e quero que o limite de arquivos suportados na hora do upload seja de 70 arquvios, só que esse limite está em apenas 6.

Pensei que fosse a configuração do php.ini, mas não é, pois lá o tamanho máximo do arquivo é de 15MB e em meu teste estou tentando fazer o upload de 40 imagens que ao todo somam apenas 3MB.

Esse é o HTML do meu formulário:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type=file multiple name="files[]" id="files[]" />
    <input type="submit" name="logar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

E esse o script usado para realizar o upload:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['logar'])) 
  {
    $files = $_FILES['files'];
    $directory = 'uploads/';

    for($i = 0, $c = count($files); $i <= $c; ++ $i) 
        {
        $upload = move_uploaded_file(
        $files['tmp_name'][$i], 
        $directory . $files['name'][$i]);
        }
  }
?>
```

Como aumentar esse limite?

Comment: Você alterou o `max_file_uploads` no php.ini?

Comment: Outra alternativa, caso não tenha como modificar o PHP.INI (servidores compartilhados) é usar algum plugin JavaScript de upload que fazem uma nova requisição para cada arquivo, driblando essa limitação.

Comment: @Laerte não achei nada de "max_file_uploads" no php.ini

Comment: Você pode adicionar ele...

Comment: @Laerte, como que adiciono?? é só colar esse código la "ini_set('max_file_uploads', 70);"??

Comment: Cola assim: `max_file_uploads = 20`

Comment: @Laerte é pra ficar assim ::: ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 15M
max_file_uploads = 70

Comment: Editei minha resposta. Tente copiar e colar no lugar do seu código PHP.

Comment: @ivan Falta um `;` entre upload_max_filesize = 15M e max_file_uploads = 70 (`upload_max_filesize = 15M; max_file_uploads = 70;`). Mas provavelmente com 70 arquivos de limite você consequentemente vai ter que aumentar o upload_max_filesize também.

Comment: o ";" fez diferença, agora sim foi

Comment: Na verdade o jeito foi adicionar a seguinte linha ao htacess php_value max_file_uploads 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `php.ini` tem sim uma diretiva que limita a quantidade de arquivos simultâneos no upload. Tente alterá-la:

```
if(isset($_POST['logar'])) {

    $files = $_FILES['files'];
    $directory = 'uploads/';

    //altera a diretiva 'max_file_uploads' do php.ini através do PHP
    ini_set('max_file_uploads', 70);

    for($i = 0, $c = count($files); $i <= $c; ++ $i) {
        $upload = move_uploaded_file(
        $files['tmp_name'][$i], 
        $directory . $files['name'][$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: não funciono, continua fazendo o upload de apenas 6

Comment: Bom, se você pode alterar o arquivo `php.ini` diretamente, então faça pelo `php.ini` mesmo.